Spring Retry for accessing implementation class name
How can I retrieve the name of the implementation class name from the RetryContext in the onError method of my RetryListener
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Backoff;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Retryable;

public abstract class ServiceBase {

    @Retryable(value = ServiceException.class, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 5000), listeners = {"myRetryListener"})
    public void start() throws ServiceException {
        fireServiceStarted("Service started");
    }
}


public class MyRetryListener implements RetryListener {

    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> boolean open(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback) {
        // Log when retry operation starts
        return true; // proceed with retry
    }

    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> void close(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
        // Log when retry operation ends
    }

    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
        // Log each error during retry
    }
}

I am trying to get the name of the implementation class name from the RetryContext in the onError method of your RetryListener implementation. However, I am getting the name of the abstract class name instead.

You probably need to share much more info since in Java the abstract method and its implementation have the same name.

Apologies, I was actually looking for implementation class info rather than the abstract class names

OK. Can you share with us what you got and what would be an expectation? What is exactly your code how you obtain that information?

Found the solution as posted below, thank you!

Below would give the method and class names if you are having retry on
abstract method
    private static <T, E extends Throwable> String getMethodName(MethodInvocationRetryCallback callback) {
        return callback.getInvocation().getMethod().getName();
    }

    private static <T, E extends Throwable> String getClassName(MethodInvocationRetryCallback callback) {
        return callback.getInvocation().getThis().getClass().toString();
    }

